# C how to use the function uname

Tags: c, function, uname

I should write a function to get some information about the system (the most important information is the the architecture). I found the function **uname** which can be used including **sys/utsname.h**. Well, though I googled and I read the documentation, I couldn't find any example of the function and I don't understand how to use uname. Anyone can explain me how to use it? it would be great if you can write an example, too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say platform, what do you mean? x86 vs x64? Linux vs BSD? AMD vs Intel?

Comment: sorry I didn't specified, I mean for istance i686, x86, x64...

Answer (score 29):

First, include the header:

```
#include <sys/utsname.h>
```

Then, define a utsname structure:

```
struct utsname unameData;
```

Then, call uname() with a pointer to the struct:

```
uname(&unameData); // Might check return value here (non-0 = failure)
```

After this, the struct will contain the info you want:

```
printf("%s", unameData.sysname);
```

http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/sysutsname.h.html

Comment: Just remember to use `struct utsname` instead of `struct ustname` or you'll get a `error: storage size of ‘myVar’ isn’t known`.

Answer (score 26):

A fully working example is worth a thousand words. ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/utsname.h>

int main(void) {

   struct utsname buffer;

   errno = 0;
   if (uname(&buffer) < 0) {
      perror("uname");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("system name = %s\n", buffer.sysname);
   printf("node name   = %s\n", buffer.nodename);
   printf("release     = %s\n", buffer.release);
   printf("version     = %s\n", buffer.version);
   printf("machine     = %s\n", buffer.machine);

   #ifdef _GNU_SOURCE
      printf("domain name = %s\n", buffer.domainname);
   #endif

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Should use `perror`  on failure. No need to handle the `EFAULT` specially (it won't happen in your code, since `buffer` is a valid address of a local variable)

Comment: Thanks Basile. In fact `perror` is better than `switch (errno)` and I've edited the post to reflect that. The code was explicitly handling `EFAULT` because I wrote it with teaching in mind, but indeed this particular example would never get there.

Comment: uname() may return 0 in case of success, code has to be changed to `uname(&buffer) < 0`

Comment: it would be even more valuable to see the output on various machines/distros. Weird that nobody does that even though they went through the trouble of creating the code.

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation, it looks like you'd use it like so:

```
struct utsname my_uname;
if(uname(&my_uname) == -1)
   printf("uname call failed!");
else
   printf("System name: %s\nNodename:%s\nRelease:%s\nVersion:%s\nMachine:%s\n",
       my_uname.sysname, my_uname.nodename, my_uname.release,my_uname.version,my_uname.machine);
```

Answer (score 6):

The `uname()` function takes a pointer to the `utsname` structure that will store the result as input. Therefore, just make a temporary `utsname` instance, pass the address of it to `uname`, and read the content of this struct after the function succeed.

```
struct utsname retval;
if(uname(&retval) < 0) {     // <----
  perror("Failed to uname");
  // error handling...
} else {
  printf("System name = %s\n", retval.sysname);
  // print other info....
  // see http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/utsname.h.html
  //   for other members...
}
```